# How to determine RMM Pool usage

Tags: cudf

When using a [rmm pool](https://github.com/rapidsai/rmm), is it possible to query how much of the pool is occupied ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes as of https://github.com/rapidsai/rmm/pull/222;

```
rmm.get_info()
MemoryInfo(free=6867517440, total=34058272768)
```